# What is the diff between http handler and ashx

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I know that httphandler is different from an ashx file. But I heard it from somewhere that they are the same. I am not able to find any reading material that shows that these two are different.

Comment: [Does this explain it?](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/difference-between-generic-handler-and-http-handler-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ashx is to HttpHandler, what apsx is to an ASP.NET (WebForms) Page.

It's just the default extension for an `HttpHandler` and there's nothing stopping you from using a different extension and configuring your server to use that extension.